# Rails How to get encoding of file Excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, utf-8, roo-gem

Iam using Rails to build my website. My website only allow user upload excel files in encoding UTF8.

Iam using gem Roo to read file .xlsx. However I can't get encoding of a file .xlsx.

I used gem CharlockHolmes, however it don't return encoding of file. This is result when use CharlockHolmes

```
{:type=>:binary, :confidence=>100}
```

How to get encoding of excel file in Rails ?

Comment: .xlsx is a binary file. It doesn't have encoding.

Comment: You'd need to parse the file and inspect its content.

Comment: Thank Sergio Tulentsev. I am not clear at this point. If .xlsx file don't have encoding, so why I can choose encoding when save a excel file on Microsoft Excel ?

Comment: What you need is: just let `Roo` to load the file. If it fails, the encoding is wrong. That simple.

Comment: That encoding is applied to the content of the excel file. That content is then zipped. Zip files are byte streams, to which the notion of "text encoding" is not applicable.